"RustPseudoTerminal is not a constructor" when serving Angular app in linux (Playwright) docker
We have 5 Angular apps already running Playwright tests in the official Playwright Docker image. For another app, some Playwright tests have just been added as proof of concept.
However, upon first running them in Docker there was an error to serve the app, concerning @nx dependencies, which prompted me to install these:
"@nx/nx-linux-arm64-musl": "18.0.4",
"@nx/nx-linux-x64-gnu": "18.0.4",

When retrying, I got past the original error but got these logs:
 NX   Successfully ran target serve for project fe-rental-pricing
 NX   native_1.RustPseudoTerminal is not a constructor

And so the app is not running, but I'm clueless about this error.

Please share a [mcve].

If I knew what was different with this app versus the others, I wouldn't have to ask the question in the first place. :)

The problem is, nobody else knows either without any code. If in the process of minimizing the problem you solve it, great. If not, we can help.

Okay, we figured it out.
I'm not sure which step actually fixed it, but:

Set all optional dependencies to the same version as NX itself
Clear the Angular and NX cache folders
Delete the node_modules folder and package_lock.json
Add the dependencies temporarily as non-optional dependencies and npm install -f (outside of Docker) to make sure they are all present (we can't install inside the Docker for other reasons).

    "@nx/nx-darwin-arm64": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-darwin-x64": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-freebsd-x64": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-linux-arm-gnueabihf": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-linux-arm64-gnu": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-linux-arm64-musl": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-linux-x64-gnu": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-linux-x64-musl": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-win32-arm64-msvc": "^18",
    "@nx/nx-win32-x64-msvc": "^18"

